# how to call a method within a method while calling one method in the main

Tags: java

In my assignment, I have to encrypt a word by shifting its characters by on the ASCII table and then print what I have done in reverse.

I have created 2 methods one called encrypt and the other called reverse that do just that however, I cant get the proper output, but I'm sure my methods are 100% working (the program should also work with sentences as in spaces should not be encrypted)

Sample run of what I should have:

> => java Encrypt
>
> Please    enter   a sentence  or  word:   Hello   World
>
> pmmfI emspX

and conditions i should follow to recall the methods:

1. If the user supplies more than one word, they should be treated as one   string
2. main() calls encrypt(),  it  does    not call    reverse()
3. encrypt() calls  reverse() before    returning   the string
4. The  printing    of  the string  happens in  main()

my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Encrypt {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a sentence or a word: ");
        encrypt(reverse(console.next()));
        
    }
    public static String reverse (String text){

        for( int i = text.length()-1 ; i >= 0; i--){

            System.out.print(text.charAt(i));
        }

        return text;
    }
    public static String encrypt (String text){

        for( int i =0 ; i < text.length(); i++){

            char X = text.charAt(i); 
            int ascii = (int)X;
            if(ascii == 32){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            else {
                System.out.print((char) (ascii+1) );
            }

        }
        return text;
    }
}
```

I didn't know what to do in the main since I don't know how to get that output while only calling 1 of the methods which is encrypt

hopefully I wasn't very confusing

Comment: Your methods simply shouldn't use `System.out.println` at all. They should be constructing a string according to the instructions, and returning that string. Then you can call the method by using for example `String something = encrypt(inputString);`, and then you can print the `something` in the `main`. And why are you using `Scanner` if the instructions are to use the command line arguments as input?

Comment: we got updated by email that we need to use scanner instead
can you please tell me where exactly the code should be edited

Comment: OK, so [edit] your question and update the instructions. And as it stands, the program doesn't use the scanner, it just prints a prompt.

Comment: just edited my question thanks for pointing things out for me, now where did i go wrong writing this code

Comment: As I said, you shouldn't be using `System.out.println` in your methods **at all**. Only in main. In your methods, you should **construct a string**.

Comment: what code should i use instead of  "System.out.println", i fully understand that i should not be printing a line, but i do not know any code that would construct a string without printing it (Still taking an introductory course to java so you can say i do not know everything yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling `System.out.println()` you should add the chars to the String returned:

```
public static String reverse (String text){
        String ret = "";
        for( int i = text.length()-1 ; i >= 0; i--){

           ret=ret+text.charAt(i);
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

Do the same with the other method, and then, in your main, call

```
System.out.println(encrypt(reverse(console.nextLine())));
```

Comment: does using System.out.println(encrypt(reverse(console.nextLine()))); go against the running conditions provided?

thanks for the help really appreciate it.

Comment: the code now works but it wont encrypt if i use two words, it will only work when the user inputs 1 word, it then ignores the other

Comment: 1. readLine() ignores spaces and reads the whole line, so different words as one

Comment: Anyways, if theres a problem, you could do something like `while console.hasNextLine(){console.nextLine()}` to make sure everything is scanned

Comment: thank you so much for your help. i know know how to properly construct a string rather than being limited to printing it 100% of the time. :)

Answer (score 2):

What you are currently doing is fundamentally wrong since it always returns raw input. It's more like a **void** method. You must store the encrypted String inside the method and return it as follows.

```
 public static String encrypt(String text) {
    StringBuilder encrypted=new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {

        char X = text.charAt(i);
        int ascii = (int) X;
        if (ascii == 32) {
            encrypted.append(" ");
        } else {
            encrypted.append((char) (ascii + 1));
        }

    }
    return encrypted.toString();
}
```

Main method should be as follows

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a sentence or a word: ");
    String encrypted=encrypt(console.nextLine());
    System.out.println(reverse(encrypted));

}
```

Comment: i agree but im kinda limited to what i know right now
i just know basic prints, parameters, math lib., command line input, scanners, for loops, nested for loops and if statements.

Comment: One day or another you have to learn them somehow. Hope you could understand my solution.